# QGIS Attribute Table Change in 2.18

Tags: qgis

When I open the attribute table in QGIS 2.14 it looks like this:

[image]

In 2.18 the attribute table for the same project looks like this:

[image]

How do I make the attribute table of 2.18 look like the attribute table of 2.14?  How can I get the 2.18 attribute table to display the rows and columns that I see in 2.14?

Comment: Perhaps you have certain tools/features selected as default in QGIS 2.18?

Answer (score 6):

here is the solution shown in the screen capture

[image: Il suffit d'appuyer sur l’icône en bas a droite de la table]